# Const vector values vs pointer?

Tags: c++, vector, constants

In C++ I know how to pass a vector as pointer:

```
void my_func (vector<int>* arr)
```

But how can I implement:

1. Make the vector const, ie don't allow change of arr = ...
2. Make the values of the vector const, ie don't allow changes to the values of arr.

I read a lot of posts here but got too much confused about const meaning with complex DS like vector and others.

Answer (score 2):

Both of your desires can be satisfied by tagging the argument as `const`:

```
void my_func(const vector<int> * arr)
```

... although unless you need to be able to pass a NULL-pointer for some reason, it's better to pass the array by-reference than by-pointer:

```
void my_func(const vector<int> & arr)
```

Note that you can have both (1) and (2), or neither, but not one-and-not-the-other.  Modifying the member-values of the vector is considered modifying the vector, so tagging the vector as `const` prohibits both types of modification.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the situation is

```
void do_something( std::vector<int>* ptr_to_vec) {
    ptr_to_vec->push_back(42);
    (*ptr_to_vec)[0] = 5;
}

void cannot_do_something(const std::vector<int>* ptr_to_vec) {
    // both of the following will not compile
    //ptr_to_vec->push_back(42);
    //(*ptr_to_vec)[0] = 5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rule of thumb: `const` applies to the thing on its left, unless there is nothing there, then it applies to the thing on its right instead.

So...

> Make the vector const, ie don't allow change of arr = ...

`vector<int>* const arr` will apply `const` to `*`, ie `arr` will be a `const` pointer to a non-const `vector`.  `arr` itself can't be changed to point at a different `vector` object, but the `vector` itself can have its members modified when accessed via `arr`.

> Make the values of the vector const, ie don't allow changes to the values of arr.

`const vector<int>* arr` (or `vector<int> const * arr`) will apply `const` to `vector`, ie `arr` will be a non-const pointer to a `const vector` object. The `vector`'s members can't be modified when accessed via `arr`, but `arr` itself can be changed to point at a different `const vector` object.

And then, you can combine the two, if needed:

`const vector<int>* const arr` (or `vector<int> const * const arr`) will make `arr` be a `const` pointer to a `const vector` object.  Neither the pointer nor the `vector` can be changed/modified.